# Migrating from MongoDB to ClickHouse: Denormalization and nested entities

Tags: mongodb, clickhouse

What level of normalization should the data entity structure have in ClickHouse for optimal performance?

Say I got a Session entity which inside has a Channel entity, which contains a bunch of fields.

In MongoDB, you can just nest them, in a denormalized fashion. 
In ClickHouse, is it recommended to denormalize this kind of fields into the Session table? Would the size increase have a noticeable effect? Would queries be noticeably more performant since no joins are needed?

Comment: How large in bytes are those Session and Channel entities on 50/90/99/99.9 percentile?

Comment: Session: 150/200/200/200 bytes approx. 
Channel: 50/100/120/125 bytes approx. 
However Channel is also present in entity Pageview: 727/899/984/1252 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Then it sounds like Channel can just be a column with Nested type inside Session/Pageview tables: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/data_types/nested_data_structures/nested/

Or if each Channel is actually not that tied to each event, probably you could store ChannelID in tables, and then resolve that "bunch of fields" via dictionaries functionality: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/dicts/external_dicts/

Comment: Nested types work in CH as "Nested tables", i.e. one entry may have a number of entries in the nested table. In this case it is a 1-1 relationship, so wouldn't it be better to just denormalize the fields right into the Session table? Pros/Cons?
Re. dictionaries, maybe it makes sense for some of the Channel fields but not for all (some can only hold values from a known set which would be OK, but other fields are totally variable).